# How to use the metric conversion

Tags: volume, unit-of-measure

I know how to use the metric conversion (K h d b d m c) when converting length to length for example 1 m squared to cm, etc.
But I want to know how to use the metric conversion when converting from volume to length, for example 1 L to meters or 1 cl to mm, etc. 
How can you use the metric conversion for this type of task? 
I can't remember 1 squared m= 1000 L or 1 dm squared= 1 L. I need to thoroughly know how to convert volume to length and vice versa.

Comment: 1 liter is not equal to 1 dm squared, but rather $1L=1dm^3$. The square meter does measure areas, while the cubic meter measures volumes.

Comment: This may help:http://www.tutorvista.com/content/math/basic-units-of-measurement/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can convert volume to length. That seems like it's defying physics or something. I think you mean that you want to convert one unit of volume to another unit of volume. It happens that this second unit of volume is the cube of a length unit. For example, if I have a cube that measure 1 meter (m) in length on each side, then the volume $V$ of the cube is
$$V = 1\text{ m}\times1\text{ m}\times1\text{ m} = 1\text{ m}^3$$
In other words, you want to convert to the cube of a measurement of length, or something along those lines. This can be achieved in various ways, which you can find [at this site.](http://www.convert-me.com/en/convert/volume/liter.html)